# Create Json structure using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

My model class is as under:

```
public class Details
    {
        public Customer customer{ get; set; }
        public List<Point> points{ get; set; }
        public List<Color> colors { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is how populate my model:-

```
    Details details = new Details();

     var info = gets data from service
                    foreach (var item in info)
                    {
                        Points p = new Points();
                        p.value = item.value;
                       details.points= new List<Dial>();

                        fusionChartDetails.points.Add(p);
                    }

                    Color c1 = new Color();
                    c1.code = "#1";
                    Color c2 = new Color();
                    c2.code = "#2";
                    Color c3 = new Color();
                    c3.code = "#3";
                    details.colors = new List<Color>();
                    details.colors.Add(c1);

                    details.colors.Add(c2);

                    details.colors.Add(c3);
}

  var final=JsonConvert.SerializeObject<details>();
```

**Expected :json**

```
 {
     "customer": {
         "caption": "Customer 1"

     },
     "colors": {
         "color": [
             {

                 "code": "#1"
             },
             {

                 "code": "#2"
             },
             {

                 "code": "#3"
             }
         ]
     },
     "points": {
         "point": [
             {
                 "value": "10"
             }
         ]
     } }
```

**But Getting this:**

```
{
    "customer": {
        "caption": "Customer 1" 
    },
    "colors": [
        {

            "code": "#1"
        },
        {

            "code": "#2"
        },
        {

            "code": "#3"
        }
    ],
    "points": [
        {
            "value": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ther difference is that inner point  and color object is not  getting contructed in my json structure.How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a couple of additional classes:

```
public class Details
{
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Points points { get; set; }
    public Colors colors { get; set; }
}

public class Points
{
    public List<Point> point { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public List<Color> color { get; set; }
}
```

and then populate like this:

```
details.points = new Points
{
    point = new List<Point>,
};
details.points.point.add(p1);
details.points.point.add(p2);
details.points.point.add(p3);

...

details.colors = new Colors
{
    color = new List<Color>(),
};
details.colors.color.Add(c1);
details.colors.color.Add(c2);
details.colors.color.Add(c3);
```